# Is it possible to change the background color when a user scrolls <section>s?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm putting together this site, [site i'm building](http://www.tseng.co/neighbor)

The site on desktop is working properly but when I try it on mobile it does not like the snap scroll plugin that I used. So I found this other one. [One page scroll demo](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/purejs_onepage_scroll_demo.html).

The problem is that the one page scroll jQuery uses sections that are technically scrolling on top of the page. So this breaks my fade in asset and gradient background. They are technically below the fold and scroll up. The gradient background changes based on the position on a 2000px height page.

tl:dr; Is it possible to change a background color based on the content that is scrolled on a single page instead of the page itself scrolling? I've been thinking that maybe theres a way by having a scrolling div behind the content?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever it is that triggers the movement you could also have trigger a styling change.  But I doubt that'd look good.

What you probably want to do is put each section in its own div, and give each div its own color.

Comment: Is there a way to give each section it's own color then smoothly transition the color change between the sections as they scroll?

Comment: I've uploaded a version of the new scheme as it's currently working [staged version of new architecture](http://www.tseng.co/neighbor2)

Comment: So you want them to transition like in a gradient as you scroll down?  Rather than be clearly different sections like in the one page scroll demo?

Comment: The colors are changing fine for me on mobile.  But it does seem to jump around erratically.  What are you using for mobile?

Comment: I was using [SCROLLSNAP](http://benoit.pointet.info/stuff/jquery-scrollsnap-plugin/) and it was working fine but then on mobile it doesn't like that scheme it causes the bouncing. So I switched to using [ONE PAGE SCROLL](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/purejs_onepage_scroll_demo.html). See my use of [One Page scroll here](http://www.tseng.co/neighbor2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) instead.

It provides the option `scrollBar:true` (among many others) so your animations will keep working as expected.

[Demo here](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrollBar.html).

Comment: This looks promising. I can't seem to figure out how to get it integrated into my site. It makes no sense to my pea sized brain.

Comment: okay so I sort of got it to work and then realized that it had the same issue as my second implementation. This is scrolling content over a stationary page so it still breaks my gradient background and fade in.

Comment: @piechart you shouldn't have any problem by triggering actions on scroll if you use the option `scrollBar:true`. I'm not quite sure what you mean when you say "This is scrolling content over a stationary page".

Comment: OKAY! I totally figured out what you were saying and i got it working. It also looks pretty great on mobile. However it's running super slow on the phone. The snap to takes a few seconds to catch up. Any thoughts?

Comment: Okay so it looks like part of the problem is that on the phone the top url bar is present so it calculates the container size with the bar open, but then the bar collapses and so it remains the same size that it was set at when the bar was open so a little bit of the next section appears.

Comment: @piechart there's no a proper solution for it. Mobile browsers don't provide a way to deal with those cases.